# specific filtering on a R Data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to apply a filter on my R data frame. Basically given a data frame I want to select rows which have value > N in all the colums.

N could be any float

```
             N_0m    N_10m    N_30m     N_1h       N_2h     N_6h
TCONS_00000001 26.23550 9.699170 6.766650 8.218550 13.2213000 9.292600
TCONS_00000002  5.63183 0.720824 1.043490 2.022020  3.5085200 0.000000
TCONS_00000003  1.79447 0.931127 1.485220 1.518330  0.0730952 0.000000
TCONS_00000004 17.07330 2.408020 1.263210 1.479090  1.7122500 1.121740
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply

```
df[apply(df > N, 1, all),,drop=FALSE]
```

if your data frame is `df`. See `?apply` for more.